# Lock screen often freezes

Tags: fedora, screen-lock

About half the time when I lock the screen, the computer becomes unresponsive and the clock on the lock screen does not update. A hard reset does work.

I presume that there's some log that would be enlightening, but I'm new to Fedora and I have no idea where the logs are. There's a README in /var/log that recommends using something called journalctl, but it doesn't say where the actual files are located.

- Hardware: HP EliteBook 850 G3
- OS: Fedora 24

Comment: Are you able to switch TTYs and log in? `CTRL` + `ALT` + `F2` to change to TTY2. If you can log in that way try some usage monitoring commands like `top`, `iostat`, or `ps`.

Comment: Today, it seemed to go to sleep when I locked the screen. The monitors never came on (built-in or external). The keystroke had no effect at that point.

Comment: Does `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old` say anything after rebooting?

Comment: I don't believe that either of those files exists. I guess log files are an optional add-on in Fedora 24 with systemd? I will verify this tomorrow.

Comment: `/var/log/messages` should definitely exist

Comment: I agree. However, I can now verify that it does not.

Comment: Does `lsof -p [PID of Xorg] | grep log` return anything?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45650/discussion-between-thom-smith-and-centimane).

Comment: I am having the same issues on a Dell Latitude. Of course I checked `journalctl` but nothing suspicious was there. Now I need to restart every time my screen locks ...

Answer (score 1):

Without arguments, all collected logs are shown unfiltered:

```
journalctl
```

You can also try installing `gnome-system-log` to have a log viewer tool:

```
su -c "yum install gnome-system-log"
```